# return a partial struct

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, multidimensional-array

I'm attempting to modify several functions to return struct types without changing all of the values.  Specifically, I'm trying to resize images in various ways and return the dimensions of the new image.  I have a struct called "picspec" which contains the header information for a netpbm picture file (width, height, max color value, and a number 1-6 indicating the format).

Some picture edits might need to modify all four of these (elements? parts of the struct), but many will only affect some of them, and it would be best to leave the original values untouched in those cases.  My first instinct was to end the function with:

```
picspec newinfo = {newx, newy, void, void};
return newinfo;
```

...And I wasn't especially surprised to get a compiler error.

Note:  I realize that I could easily solve this particular problem by passing the old "picspec" as an argument, but a "keep current value" command could be very useful in other situations.  My (currently very limited) knowledge of pointers makes me think it can be done, but I haven't had much success searching for it.  ("Pointer to self" taught me all about linked lists, but it wasn't what I had in mind.)

Is there a mechanism for "keep current value" or a similarly-concise way to achieve the same goal?  If not, what's the most practical alternative?

Comment: Why not `picspec newinfo = { newx, newy, oldinfo.width, oldinfo.height };`?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the whole function. It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do. My first reaction is--if you want to return the old values for some of these parts of the struct from the function, you will need to have access to them in the function somehow. It seems like it would make sense to pass in a pointer to the old picspec in this case.

Comment: Looking back at this several months later, it seems I was trying to invent object-oriented programming before I knew what an "object" was. Thanks for the response anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to go about manipulating C structs with functions:

If you return values, you have to return entire struct. You still don't actually have to create a new copy:

```
MyStruct myStructModified(MyStruct s, int delta) {
  // s is already a copy of the original value
  s.member += delta;
  return s;
}
```

...

```
{ // somewhere else, with MyStruct s
     // replace value of s with new one
     s = myStructModified(s, 10);
}
```

Returning relatively small structs is certainly a good way to keep yourself focused on your actual problem, instead of C pointer problems, but if you want to modify existing struct, and are restricted to C (instead of C-like C++ without OOP), then you have to use pointers:

```
void modifyMyStruct(MyStruct *sp, int delta) {
  sp->member += delta;
}
```

...

```
{ // somewhere else, with MyStruct s
     // pass pointer to s to function, which will modify it in-place
     modifyMyStruct(&s, 10);
}
```

If you can use C++ compiler, there is third choice, to use C++ reference, which is just sugar-coated pointer:

```
void modifyMyStruct(MyStruct &s, int delta) {
  s.member += delta;
}
```

...

```
{ // somewhere else, with MyStruct s
     // pass reference to s to function, which will modify it in-place
     modifyMyStruct(s, 10);
}
```

Using values is cleaner and safer, but slower (copying all the data in the struct). Using pointers is efficient (only address passed, usually in CPU register, very fast), but you can very easily have a crashing bug if you do it wrong. C++ references are slightly cleaner and safer alternative to pointers, and are usually preferred, if you can use C++ compiler.

Comment: If you use a C++ compiler, you don't program in C any longer. I as well could suggest something like 'if you have a Java compiler' or 'if you have a Python runtime'.

Comment: Nevertheless +1 for the first two solutions.

Comment: @glglgl Indeed, C++ is not C, but these days it's rare (school project with rules, embedded platform) to not have C++, and in that case I would not hesitate to use certain C++ features, like references instead of pointers, and basic template functions instead of `#define` macros, even if code is otherwise C-like. After all, for nearly all "good" C code, converting it to C++ is just matter of renaming `.c` to `.cpp`...

Comment: Moving fast to irrelevant details, but if compiler-specific stuff is ok, then some (most? almost all?) compilers support at least some C99 stuff in C++ code. But I've mostly used gcc-flavoured C, and mostly before C99, so I better shut up.

Answer (score 0):

If it's really important to return a partial struct, and not pass an existing one which you manipulate, you could define a "partial struct" to be a function that manipulates a struct, and return that.

Unfortunately, C doesn't support closures. So it will get a bit ugly. You'll probably represent the closure by a function pointer and a void pointer which points to the bound variables.